# Cadence ListOpenWorkflowExecutions always returns zero

Tags: java, cadence-workflow

I am trying to query ListOpenWorkflowExecutions using WorkflowServiceTChannel. I always get ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsResponse size of 0. I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong. Following is the java code i am using.

```
            IWorkflowService cadenceService = new WorkflowServiceTChannel(ipAddress, 7933); 
            
            // Start Window
            Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            startCal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24);

            // End Window
            Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();

            StartTimeFilter timeFilter = new StartTimeFilter();
            timeFilter.setEarliestTime(startCal.getTimeInMillis());
            timeFilter.setLatestTime(endCal.getTimeInMillis());
            ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest request = new ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest();
            request.setStartTimeFilter(timeFilter);
            request.setDomain("staging");
            ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsResponse response = 
            cadenceService.ListOpenWorkflowExecutions(request);
            System.out.println(response.getExecutionsSize());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a way. Timestamp shall be in nanos instead of mills. Following code worked for me.

Thanks to Maxim who helped me on Cadence slack channel.

```
StartTimeFilter timeFilter = new StartTimeFilter();
            timeFilter.setEarliestTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000));
            timeFilter.setLatestTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis() + 100000));
            ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest request = new ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest();
            request.setStartTimeFilter(timeFilter);
            request.setDomain(domain);
            ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsResponse response = cadenceService.ListOpenWorkflowExecutions(request);
            int openWorkflows = response.getExecutionsSize();
            LOG.info("open workflows - {}, domain - {}", openWorkflows, domain);
```